# Property of projection matrix $P = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ under random design context

Tags: statistics, least-squares, linear-regression

In OLS with fixed design, we project $Y$ onto the column space of design matrix $X$, which is $\mathcal{C}(X)$. The residual $Y-PY = (I-P)Y$ is orthogonal $\mathcal{C}(X)$.

Further more, $(I-P)$ is a projection onto $\mathcal{C}(X)^{\perp}$, so $(I-P)X = 0$.

Now consider a random design matrix $X$, where each row is i.i.d a $p$-dimensional sub-Gaussian random vector. I understand the space $\mathcal{C}(X)$ is random. May I ask if the classic property about projection matrix $(I-P)$ still holds in this context?

Comment: Sure. It's just a pointwise property. That is, we have a probability space $\Omega$, and for each $\omega\in \Omega$, we have a realization $X=X(\omega)$. Then for each fixed $\omega$, $P=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is the projection onto $\mathcal{C}(X)$. But now $P$ and the space $\mathcal{C}(X)$ itself will be different for different $\omega$. But for each fixed $\omega$, what you say is true. The matrix $P(\omega)$ will be the projection onto $\mathcal{C}(X(\omega))$ and $I-P(\omega)$ will be the projection onto its orthogonal complement.